# Adding properties to abstract class which are already extending from that abstract class

Tags: java, oop, abstract

I have an abstract class A. There are at least 10 other concrete classes that are extending from Abstract class A. Class C is one of those concrete classes. I have a requirement to add a property of type C to all those classes. The best way would have been to add that to class A so as to avoid code duplication. However since C is also extending from A, this would not be possible.
Is there any way to achieve the above?

Comment: consider accepting my answer if this has helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe consider using an Interface. Though java does not support multiple class inheritance, it does allow for multiple implementations of an interface. This way, you would be able to have the methods you need in C, can be stored in an interface, that way other classes that need that method, can inherit them from the interface, and also use the abstract class at the same time.